# Trouble With Linq Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I'm having difficulties writing my linq query. Not sure where to put my Where clause.

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get())
        {
            Interaction = new BindableCollection<InteractionDTO>(
                ctx.Interactions.Select(
                x => new InteractionDTO
                {
                    Indepth = x.Indepth  
                }
                )
           );
        }
```

where do I put this code or how do i write it in a manner it'll work with the syntax above.
`where date>= StartDate.SelectedDate.Value`

Comment: Date is a member of the interaction Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
ctx.Interactions.
   .Where(x => x.date >= StartDate.SelectedDate.Value) 
   .Select(x => new InteractionDTO
            {
                Indepth = x.Indepth  
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
            ctx.Interactions
            .where (x=> date >=x.StartDate)
            .Select(x => new InteractionDTO
            {
                Indepth = x.Indepth  
            });
```